# MVCApplication in Asp.net with different projects folders

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC application. I am trying to implement use Model data in view. MVC application  consists of separate project for model controller and view.I dont understand how to access Users.cs in Partialviews Details.cshtml since User.cs is in different project within same solution.Thanks

Comment: Is it requirement for your project to keep Model, View and Controller in separate Projects? Or are you missing something? Generally all three directories resides in single project.

Comment: Yes it is requirement.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add a reference to that project.
Then you'll be able to add the namespace with the `using` statement in files where you want to access it.

[Adding Ref screenshot in VS 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIkmK.png)

**EDIT**
Sorry.. can't comment  yet. According to the error, its taking 'MvcApplication' as type instead of namespace. It may be a silly question; but do you have a class named 'MvcApplication'?

**EDIT 2** ok next question.. when you type @model MvcApplication and hover over it.. does it show up as a namespace?

Comment: No there is no class named MvcApplication.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "Add to reference". The project containing the partial view need to reference the project containing Users.cs 
Afterwards you can use the 'using' keyword in classes and views to reference the class Users.cs

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I added reference to MvcApplication.Contracts and while using @model MvcApplication.Contracts it gives error stating 
'The type name 'Contracts' does not exist in the type 'MvcApplication'.Thanks

Comment: Click on where it is causing the error and press alt + enter